# Reactjs. Use Ref inside the component and outside

Tags: reactjs

I wrote a custom input for passwords. He looks like this:

```
const InputPassword = ({placeholder}) => {
    const inputRef = useRef()
    const [isPasswordVisible, setPasswordVisible] = useState(false)
  
    function setInputStatus() {
        if (isPasswordVisible) {
            inputRef.current.setAttribute('type', 'password')
        } else {
            inputRef.current.setAttribute('type', 'text')
        }
        setPasswordVisible(!isPasswordVisible)
    }

    return (
        <div className={cl.main}>
            <input
                ref={inputRef}
                type={"password"}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                className={cl.input}
            />
            <div className={cl.eyeContainer} onClick={setInputStatus}>
                <Eye
                    isPasswordVisible={isPasswordVisible}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default InputPassword;
```

Now I want to get the value from my input in the parent component. The best way to do this is to use a forwardRef, but my component already has an internal Ref that is needed to change the type of the input. Surely you can somehow use one Ref to solve these two problems, but I did not find how.

I tried to pass a Boolean type state from the parent, so that when this state changes, call a method in the child component, this method would change another state in the parent, which stores the value from the child. And when this parent state changes, the necessary logic would work out for me. But the code turned out to be just as cumbersome and confusing as what is written above. Naturally, such code does not work well, it shows unpredictable behavior. I'm sure the solution is much simpler.

Comment: Why not use a callback? I think that your case is just the typical scenario when you can make a good use of a callback. By that, I mean adding the on<...> prop which will be accepting a function from a parent component, and arguments from a child component.

Comment: I know well how to call the callback from the child component (when the button is in the child component), but in my case the button is in the parent component and I don’t understand how to call the child’s callback when it is pressed.

Comment: You just want the data from the child, or do you want to manipulate the child in some way? I think you should explore Context API, if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also pass a `state` variable to the child component, I am passing a `ref` variable, assuming that the parent component does not need to re-render based on the changes in the value of `variable` that is being passed as a `prop`.

Your parent component should have a `inputRef`, and pass it as a `prop` to child component, something like this:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef()
  
  return <InputPassword inputRef={inputRef} />
}

export default Parent;
```

```
const InputPassword = ({placeholder, inputRef}) => {
    const [isPasswordVisible, setPasswordVisible] = useState(false)
  
    function setInputStatus() {
        if (isPasswordVisible) {
            inputRef.current.setAttribute('type', 'password')
        } else {
            inputRef.current.setAttribute('type', 'text')
        }
        setPasswordVisible(!isPasswordVisible)
    }

    return (
        <div className={cl.main}>
            <input
                ref={inputRef}
                type={"password"}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                className={cl.input}
            />
            <div className={cl.eyeContainer} onClick={setInputStatus}>
                <Eye
                    isPasswordVisible={isPasswordVisible}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default InputPassword
```

Comment: Many thanks. Your way worked for me. I didn't know that this can be done, tell me how this method differs from forwardRef and in what cases should one or the other be used?

Comment: I have given a reason in the answer itself, why one should use this method instead of passing a state as a prop.

Comment: @ИгорьМешалкин I have used concept of forwarding ref's.